# HTML input type number min & max attributes not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I created a table in HTML and for each of the numeric input fields I put a minimum and maximum range. When I run the demo in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox I see the small increment and decrements arrows to the far right. But when I run the same application in IE the up & down arrows do not show.

My question is: is there a way to make it show in IE, or, is there no support available for this yet?

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

span {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My first input test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="PatientTrackingBoardTable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="TopRow">Inventory</th>
        <th class="TopRow">Qty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="SubRow">
      <td class="InventoryRow" style="width:75%">Chairs</td>
      <td class="QtyAvailableCell">
        <input id="ChairsAvailable" type="number" class="BedInputField" min="0" max="100" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SubRow">
      <td class="InventoryRow">Tables</td>
      <td class="QtyAvailableCell">
        <input id="TablesAvailable" type="number" class="BedInputField" min="0" max="100" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 10, and 11 both allow type input: number - but you don't get the UI spinner buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript or jQuery to do this kind of change in IE.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keydown(function () {
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
    $(this).data("old", $(this).val());
  });
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    if (!$(this).val() || (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 11 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0))
      ;
    else
      $(this).val($(this).data("old"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" max="11" value="0"/>
```

Hope this helps.